# How to shrink/decrease the hit area of a button in android?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, touch

I've tried TouchDelegate which said to achieve so. It works for increase the hit area but doesn't work to decrease the hit area.

And can we change the hit area just in the xml file?

My test code just copy from [Extend a Child View's Touchable Area](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/viewgroup.html#delegate), in which said that 'You can also use this approach to shrink the child's touch region if need be.'.

Comment: I've tried to use  delegateArea.right -= 100;  
 delegateArea.bottom -= 100;

Answer (score 0):

In the link you have provided:

```
 // Extend the touch area of the ImageButton beyond its bounds  
 // on the right and bottom.  
 delegateArea.right += 100;  
 delegateArea.bottom += 100;
```

change it to:

```
 delegateArea.right -= 100;  
 delegateArea.bottom -= 100;
```

now you will get the desired result. you might want to change the value from 100 to a value you deem fit.

Comment: I did so but didn't work! I click by the edge and the button still hitten.